# Wpf enable to delete row by user but disable to edit cell on DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf

I have DataGrid that bind a list
I have a method of ADD data and I want to let the user delete by chose the row with the mouse and use the delete button

The ADD method can add specific data that choose from Combobox and I don't want to let the user change the data directly by edit cell

I have try to set  DataGrid.IsReadOnly = false and DataGridTextColumn.IsReadOnly = true
But the delete not work...

To add data I choose data by the Comboboxes and Click Button to execute method: `AddNewData`
It's doing ok..

How can I do it?

My Relevant DataGrid Named  : x:Name="ShiftsGrid"

My Code Behind :

```
using Shifts.ModelView;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Shifts.Windows
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ShiftsManager.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ShiftsManager : Window
    {
        public ShiftsManager()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ShiftsManagerMV(Close);
            Closing += ((ShiftsManagerMV)DataContext).ShiftsManager_Closing;
        }
    }
}
```

All my XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="Shifts.Windows.ShiftsManager"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Shifts.Windows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ShiftsManager" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5 0 0 0">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="{Binding  Source={x:Reference PositionDescriptionColumn}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="תיאור עמדה" FontSize="15" />
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding PositionDescriptionColumnFilter,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="15" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="{Binding  Source={x:Reference ShiftsTypeDescriptionColumn}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"  Text="סוג משמרת" FontSize="15"/>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding ShiftsTypeDescriptionColumnFilter,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="15"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>

                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="{Binding  Source={x:Reference DaysTypeDescriptionColumn}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"  Text="יום המשמרת" FontSize="15"/>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding DaysTypeDescriptionColumnFilter,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="15"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>

                </StackPanel>

                <DataGrid CanUserDeleteRows="True" IsEnabled="true" FontSize="15" IsReadOnly="False"
                          x:Name="ShiftsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Shifts,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          BorderBrush="#FF1600F0" AlternatingRowBackground="SkyBlue" AlternationCount="2" SelectionMode="Single" Height="224"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentShifts,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

         
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF001389"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#CDCCFF"/>

                        </Style>

                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Id}" Value="-1">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFAE00"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#0051ff"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>

                    </DataGrid.Resources>

                    <DataGrid.Columns>

                        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="150" IsReadOnly="True"  x:Name="PositionDescriptionColumn" HeaderStringFormat="" Header="מספר עובד" Binding="{Binding Position.Description}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>



                        <DataGridTextColumn  MinWidth="150" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="ShiftsTypeDescriptionColumn" HeaderStringFormat="" Header="מספר עובד" Binding="{Binding ShiftsType.Description}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>



                        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="150" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="DaysTypeDescriptionColumn" HeaderStringFormat="" Header="מספר עובד" Binding="{Binding DaysType.Description}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                </DataGrid>

                <StackPanel >
                    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="{Binding  Source={x:Reference PositionDescriptionColumn}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="תיאור עמדה" FontSize="15" />
                                <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=Description}" FontSize="15"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Positions}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=PositionsToAdd}">
                                </ComboBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                            
                        </Border>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="{Binding  Source={x:Reference ShiftsTypeDescriptionColumn}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"  Text="סוג משמרת" FontSize="15"/>
                                <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=Description}" FontSize="15"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ShiftsTypes}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ShiftsTypesToAdd}">
                                </ComboBox>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>

                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="{Binding  Source={x:Reference DaysTypeDescriptionColumn}, Path=ActualWidth}">

                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"  Text="יום המשמרת" FontSize="15" />
                                <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=Description}" FontSize="15"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DaysTypes}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DaysTypesToAdd}">
                                </ComboBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>

                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button Content="הוספה" FontSize="20" Command="{Binding AddNewData}" Background="Aquamarine"></Button>
                <Button Content="עדכן את נתוני המשמרות" FontSize="25" Background="#FF4FCFFF" Command="{Binding UpdateAllShiftData}" Margin="20"></Button>

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5 0 0 0">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="{Binding  Source={x:Reference WorkerNumberColumn}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="מספר עובד" FontSize="15" />
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding WorkerNumberColumnFilter,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="15"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="{Binding  Source={x:Reference WorkerNameColumn}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"  Text="שם עובד" FontSize="15"/>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding WorkerNameColumnFilter,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="15"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>

                </StackPanel>

                <DataGrid  x:Name="WorkersGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Workers,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                BorderBrush="#FF1600F0" AlternatingRowBackground="SkyBlue" AlternationCount="2" SelectionMode="Single" Height="224" IsReadOnly="True"
                           SelectedItem="{Binding WorkerRowSelectedRowItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="15">



                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF001389"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#CDCCFF"/>

                        </Style>

                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Purple" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>

                    </DataGrid.Resources>

                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="150" x:Name="WorkerNumberColumn" HeaderStringFormat="" Header="מספר עובד" Binding="{Binding WorkerNumber}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="150" x:Name="WorkerNameColumn" Header="שם עובד" Binding="{Binding WorkerName}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                </DataGrid>

            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
        
        
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My Model code :

```
using IniFiles;
using MilBatDBModels.Shifts;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static DataBaseManager.ShiftsDBManager;
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using MilBatDBModels.Common;
using System.Windows;
using CommonWindows;

namespace Shifts.ModelView
{
    public class ShiftsManagerMV : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Action close;
        Dictionary<long, ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt>> TableList;
        public ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt> Shifts { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers { get; set; }

        public Positions PositionsToAdd { get; set; }
        public ShiftsType ShiftsTypesToAdd { get; set; }
        public DaysType DaysTypesToAdd { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Positions> Positions { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ShiftsType> ShiftsTypes { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<DaysType> DaysTypes { get; set; }

        public bool Changed;

        private ShiftsExt currentShifts;
        public ShiftsExt CurrentShifts { 
            get 
            {

                return currentShifts;


            } 
            
            set
            {
                currentShifts = value;
            }
        }

        private Worker workerRowSelectedRowItem;
        public Worker WorkerRowSelectedRowItem
        {
            get { return workerRowSelectedRowItem; }
            set {
                workerRowSelectedRowItem = value;
                
                    UpdateShifts();
                

            }
        }
        public void ShiftsManager_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Changed)
            {
                YesNoWindow yesNoWindow = new YesNoWindow("יש נתונים שלא עודכנו, האם לעדכן אותם בבסיס הנתונים?", "כן", "לא");
                yesNoWindow.ShowDialog();
                if (yesNoWindow.ResultYes)
                {
                    UpdateAllShiftDataAction();
                }
            }
        }

        public ShiftsManagerMV(Action close)
        {
            Changed = false;
            TableList = null;
            ShiftsIniManager s = new ShiftsIniManager();
            long CurrentShiftsClass = s.GetShiftsLocalClass();
            Positions = new ObservableCollection<Positions> (ShiftsDBManagerInstance.GetPositions(CurrentShiftsClass));
            ShiftsTypes = new ObservableCollection<ShiftsType>(ShiftsDBManagerInstance.GetShiftsTypes());
            DaysTypes = new ObservableCollection<DaysType>(ShiftsDBManagerInstance.GetDaysTypes());

            UpdateWorkers();
            this.close = close;
        }

        private void UpdateShifts()
        {
            if (workerRowSelectedRowItem != null)
            {
                if (TableList[workerRowSelectedRowItem.ID] == null || TableList[workerRowSelectedRowItem.ID].Any() == false)
                {
                    TableList[workerRowSelectedRowItem.ID] = new ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt>(ShiftsDBManagerInstance.SelectShifts(workerRowSelectedRowItem.ID));
                }
                Shifts = new ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt>(TableList[workerRowSelectedRowItem.ID].Select(se => se));
            }
        }

        private void UpdateWorkers()
        {
            ShiftsIniManager s = new ShiftsIniManager();
            long _class = s.GetShiftsLocalClass();
            Workers = new ObservableCollection<Worker>
                (ShiftsDBManagerInstance.SelectWorkers(_class));

            if(TableList == null)
            {
                TableList = new Dictionary<long, ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt>>();

                for (int i = 0; i < Workers.Count; i++)
                {
                    TableList.Add(Workers[i].ID, new ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt>());
                }
            }

        }

        private string _WorkerNumberColumnFilter;
        public string WorkerNumberColumnFilter
        {
            get
            {
                return _WorkerNumberColumnFilter;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_WorkerNumberColumnFilter != value)
                {
                    _WorkerNumberColumnFilter = value;
                    RunFilterAction();
                }
            }
        }


        private string _WorkerNameColumnFilter;
        public string WorkerNameColumnFilter
        {
            get
            {
                return _WorkerNameColumnFilter;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_WorkerNameColumnFilter != value)
                {
                    _WorkerNameColumnFilter = value;
                    RunFilterAction();
                }
            }
        }

        private void RunFilterAction()
        {
            UpdateWorkers();
            List<Worker> wTemp = Workers.ToList();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_WorkerNumberColumnFilter) == false)
            {
                wTemp = wTemp.
                    Where(w => w.WorkerNumber.ToLower().Contains(_WorkerNumberColumnFilter.ToLower())).ToList();
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_WorkerNameColumnFilter) == false)
            {
                wTemp = wTemp.
                    Where(w => w.WorkerName.ToLower().Contains(_WorkerNameColumnFilter.ToLower())).ToList();
            }
            Workers = new ObservableCollection<Worker>(wTemp);
        }











        private string _PositionDescriptionColumnFilter;
        public string PositionDescriptionColumnFilter
        {
            get
            {
                return _PositionDescriptionColumnFilter;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_PositionDescriptionColumnFilter != value)
                {
                    _PositionDescriptionColumnFilter = value;
                    RunFilterShiftsAction();
                }
            }
        }


        private string _ShiftsTypeDescriptionColumnFilter;
        public string ShiftsTypeDescriptionColumnFilter
        {
            get
            {
                return _ShiftsTypeDescriptionColumnFilter;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_ShiftsTypeDescriptionColumnFilter != value)
                {
                    _ShiftsTypeDescriptionColumnFilter = value;
                    RunFilterShiftsAction();
                }
            }
        }

        private string _DaysTypeDescriptionColumnFilter;
        public string DaysTypeDescriptionColumnFilter
        {
            get
            {
                return _DaysTypeDescriptionColumnFilter;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_DaysTypeDescriptionColumnFilter != value)
                {
                    _DaysTypeDescriptionColumnFilter = value;
                    RunFilterShiftsAction();
                }
            }
        }

        private void RunFilterShiftsAction()
        {
            UpdateShifts();
            List<ShiftsExt> sTemp = Shifts.ToList();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_PositionDescriptionColumnFilter) == false)
            {
                sTemp = sTemp.
                    Where(s => s.Position.Description.ToString().ToLower().Contains(_PositionDescriptionColumnFilter.ToLower())).ToList();
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_ShiftsTypeDescriptionColumnFilter) == false)
            {
                sTemp = sTemp.
                    Where(s => s.ShiftsType.Description.ToLower().Contains(_ShiftsTypeDescriptionColumnFilter.ToLower())).ToList();
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_DaysTypeDescriptionColumnFilter) == false)
            {
                sTemp = sTemp.
                    Where(s => s.DaysType.Description.ToLower().Contains(_DaysTypeDescriptionColumnFilter.ToLower())).ToList();
            }
            Shifts = new ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt>(sTemp);
        }


        

        private ICommand _AddNewData;
        public ICommand AddNewData
        {
            get
            {
                if (_AddNewData == null)
                {
                    _AddNewData = new RelayCommand((param) => AddNewDataAction());
                }
                return _AddNewData;
            }
        }

        private void AddNewDataAction()
        {
            Changed = true;
            if (Shifts.Where(se=>(se.DaysType.Code == DaysTypesToAdd.Code) && (se.ShiftsType.Code == ShiftsTypesToAdd.Code)).Any())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("לא ניתן לתת לאותו עובד את אותה משמרת באותו יום");
                return;
            }
            Worker w = workerRowSelectedRowItem;
            Shifts.Add(new ShiftsExt(-1, 
                new Worker(w.ID, w.WorkerNumber, w.WorkerName,w.Address,w.City,w.PhoneNumber,w.PhoneNumber2,w.Number,w.ClassCode),
                new Positions(PositionsToAdd.Code, PositionsToAdd.Description, PositionsToAdd.ClassCode),
                new ShiftsType(ShiftsTypesToAdd.Code, ShiftsTypesToAdd.Description),
                new DaysType(DaysTypesToAdd.Code, DaysTypesToAdd.Description)));

            TableList[workerRowSelectedRowItem.ID] = new ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt>(Shifts.Select(se => se));


            //ShiftsIniManager s = new ShiftsIniManager();
            //for (int i = 0; i < Workers.Count(); i++)
            //{
            //    Workers[i].ClassCode = s.GetShiftsLocalClass();
            //}
            //List<Worker> wTemp = Workers.ToList();
            //wTemp.RemoveAll(w => w.WorkerName == null);
            //ShiftsDBManagerInstance.UpdateWorkers(wTemp);
            //UpdateWorkers();
        }


        private ICommand _UpdateAllShiftData;
        public ICommand UpdateAllShiftData
        {
            get
            {
                if (_UpdateAllShiftData == null)
                {
                    _UpdateAllShiftData = new RelayCommand((param) => UpdateAllShiftDataAction());
                }
                return _UpdateAllShiftData;
            }
        }

        private void UpdateAllShiftDataAction()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < TableList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (TableList.ElementAt(i).Value.Any()) {
                    ShiftsDBManagerInstance.UpdateShifts(TableList.ElementAt(i).Value.ToList());
                }
            }


           
            //ShiftsIniManager s = new ShiftsIniManager();
            //for (int i = 0; i < Workers.Count(); i++)
            //{
            //    Workers[i].ClassCode = s.GetShiftsLocalClass();
            //}
            //List<Worker> wTemp = Workers.ToList();
            //wTemp.RemoveAll(w => w.WorkerName == null);
            //ShiftsDBManagerInstance.UpdateWorkers(wTemp);
            //UpdateWorkers();
            MessageBox.Show("השינוי עודכן בהצלחה");
            Changed = false;



            for (int i = 0; i < Workers.Count(); i++)
            {
                TableList[Workers[i].ID] = new ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt>(ShiftsDBManagerInstance.SelectShifts(Workers[i].ID));
            }

            if (TableList[WorkerRowSelectedRowItem.ID].Any())
            {
                Shifts = new ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt>(TableList[WorkerRowSelectedRowItem.ID].Select(se => se));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the bound collection defined, how do you add and delete rows? What exactly does not work, only deleting or adding or preventing editing?

Comment: @thatguy  I add more information..

Comment: @thatguy  Never mind.. I found my problem

Answer (score 0):

I forget to update my main map

I have create

```
 private ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt> CopyActualList() {
            return new ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt>(Shifts.Select(se => se));
        }
```

And update my map as  `TableList[workerRowSelectedRowItem.ID] = CopyActualList();`

in

```
 private void UpdateAllShiftDataAction()
        {
            TableList[WorkerRowSelectedRowItem.ID] = CopyActualList();
            for (int i = 0; i < TableList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (TableList.ElementAt(i).Value.Any()) {
                    ShiftsDBManagerInstance.UpdateShifts(TableList.ElementAt(i).Value.ToList());
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("השינוי עודכן בהצלחה");
            Changed = false;



            for (int i = 0; i < Workers.Count(); i++)
            {
                TableList[Workers[i].ID] = new ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt>(ShiftsDBManagerInstance.SelectShifts(Workers[i].ID));
            }

            if (TableList[WorkerRowSelectedRowItem.ID].Any())
            {
                Shifts = new ObservableCollection<ShiftsExt>(TableList[WorkerRowSelectedRowItem.ID].Select(se => se));
            }
        }
```

and

```
 public Worker WorkerRowSelectedRowItem
        {
            get { return workerRowSelectedRowItem; }
            set {

                if(workerRowSelectedRowItem != null && TableList != null)
                {
                    TableList[workerRowSelectedRowItem.ID] = CopyActualList();
                }
                workerRowSelectedRowItem = value;
                UpdateShifts();
            }
        }
```